# Symfony2 Unidirectional ManyToMany Collection Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

I'm stuck :-)

Maybe I just have the wrong keywords in my research. But I don't get through. So I hope one of the crowd can help me!

I have a unidirectional ManyToMany Association. When I try to submit the form (and therefore persist), I get the error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'TrainerInnenPool\AppBundle\Entity\Trainer#applicationFields' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: TrainerInnenPool\AppBundle\Entity\ApplicationField@0000000022ef36c600000000087bcbc3.

When I do "cascade persist" a new Entity is created which actually already exists.

I have 2 Entities:

- Trainer
- ApplicationField

The Trainer has a unidirectional ManyToMany association to the ApplicationField:

```
class Trainer {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applicationFields = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationField")
     */
    protected $applicationFields;
```

The ApplicationField has a self-referencing OneToMany association:

```
class ApplicationField {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationField", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApplicationField", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;
```

I want to create a form where I can add a Trainer - ApplicationField association.

Therefore I have an ApplicationFieldCollectionType:

```
class ApplicationFieldCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('applicationFields', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => new ApplicationFieldType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'label' => false
                ))
       ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TrainerInnenPool\AppBundle\Entity\Trainer',
        ));
    }
```

The embeded Type is as follows:

```
class ApplicationFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('applicationFieldName', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TrainerInnenPoolAppBundle:ApplicationField',
                'label' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('application_field')
                        ->where('application_field.parent is NULL');
                }
        )); 

        $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TrainerInnenPoolAppBundle:ApplicationField',
                'label' => false,
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('application_field')
                        ->where('application_field.parent = 1');
                }
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TrainerInnenPool\AppBundle\Entity\ApplicationField',
        ));
    }
```

Last missing part: The controller:

```
    public function editApplicationField($id, Request $request)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $trainer = $entityManager->getRepository('TrainerInnenPoolAppBundle:Trainer')->find($id);

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new ApplicationFieldCollectionType(), $trainer);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $editForm->handleRequest($request);

            $entityManager->flush();
        }
```

When I fetch the ApplicationField entities from the Trainer and try to persist those,

```
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        $af = $trainer->getApplicationFields();

        foreach ($af as $applicationField) {
            $trainer->addApplicationField($applicationField);
            $entityManager->persist($applicationField);
        }

        $entityManager->flush();
```

I'm not able to do so, since I get a "Duplicate Entry For Key PRIMARY" - Exception.

I think I terribly miss any obvious point. If someone could help me, gave me a hint or just mentioned to update my question with information, I would be so thankful.

Kind regards...

Answer (score 1):

Your nested type setters are not called because of a missing property:

```php
->add('applicationFields', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => new ApplicationFieldType(),
                ...
                'by_reference' => false
                ...
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

When you plan to have collection fields that are addable/deletable("allow_add", "allow_delete"), you should always provide the "by_reference" => false option, in order to call the setters directly on the related entities and then build the association, rather than chain methods from the original entity.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need the cascade={"persist"} annotation because you want to persist the whole entity with its association to ApplicationField. If you don't use cascade={"persist"}, you'd have to manually persist the entities.

The entities are already added to the trainer, so if you want to manually persist the entities you should remove the line

```
$trainer->addApplicationField($applicationField);
```

and only execute the persist.

This should work. Try it. But I think the effect will be the same as if you use cascade persist. So it's not the final solution I think, but the first step to understand the problem, why the manual persist didn't work before.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Indeed, it is a first approach. The relation is persisted. Still a new ApplicationField entity is created. I think the point is anywhere I lose the reference, although at the point of persisting manually the ApplicationField entity with the original ID still exists.

Comment: Right. Already thinking about it. I've never used an unidirectional manytomany, so it's first time experience. I think the problem is that when you add an entity to the trainer it doesn't recognize the entity is already managed. Try the following: $entityManager -> getUnitOfWork() -> getEntityState($applicationField) in the loop. Check if the entities are marked as managed or as new ones. If they are marked as new ones, the problem is the handleRequest method that doesn't handle the request properly.

Comment: Indeed, the state is "2" -> STATE_NEW; So I guess, there is no way to go on without doing everything manually...?

Comment: Symfony has changed a lot on forms the last few updates. I've always used bind() or bindRequest(). I don't know which call actually works, but try to use bindRequest instead of handleRequest. bind() is 100% deprecated.

Comment: Hey bindRequest doesn't exist anymore. Actually in another project (Symfony 2.0) I'm also used to use bindRequest(). However, doesn't solve the prob. bind() performs equivalent to handleRequest().

Comment: Have you tried to set the data_class of ApplicationFieldType? Something in your architecture is wrong, but I can't find it right now. It's no solution to make it manually. There must be a way

Comment: I'm asked to avoid discussions, but i've not enogh rep to chat - funny... I'm with you, something must be wrong about the architecture. However, ApplicationFieldType has data_class => [...]\ApplicationField and ApplicationFieldCollectionType has data_class => ...\Trainer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45326/discussion-between-user3199050-and-mike)